# Java Hibernate EntityManager merge() always want to insert nulls for all fields

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am having issues with the very simple EntityManager merge() method.
If the entry record does not exist in the DB (based on the PK) it should be inserted, otherwise updated. But in my case, merge() updates records fine but when needs to insert, instead of inserting the values of the entity object,  is trying to insert nulls in all the fields. So I get the following error:

> SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("REFDATA"."CLIENT"."ID")

This is my repository and entity code:

```js
@Repository
public class BenDAOImpl implements BenDAO {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveBen(Ben ben) {
        em.merge(ben);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Ben implements Serializable{

    @Id
    public String id;
    @Id
    public String ownerId;
    public String country;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Ben other = (Ben) obj;
        return id.equals(other.id) && ownerId.equals(other.ownerId);
    }
}
```

If I replace merge by persist, the record is inserted with no errors.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01400 Said that your id is null. Try to set idGenerator to id field.
Sorry, I did not immediately notice that you have two IDs. You must do something like that. Becouse it is composite key

```
@Entity @IdClass(ProjectId.class)
public class Project {
    @Id String id;
    @Id String ownerId;
     :
}

Class ProjectId {
    String id;
    String ownerId;
}
```

Comment: hi @ЮлийЩербак, I have assigned a value manually to it: Ben bn = new Ben();
  bn.id = "01";
  bn.ownerId = "01";
  bn.country = "SP";
  benService.saveBen(bn);

Comment: |@ A Torre Sorry, I did not immediately notice that you have two IDs. You must do something like that